# Commands not working

Tags: rosinstall, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

commands in 1.2 rosinstall like Desktop-Full Install in http://wiki.ros.org/action/login/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu/Source doesn't work. it returns the 404 ERROR: NOT FOUND.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189587/commands-not-working/) by [Rm4n2aa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19982/rm4n2aa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-10**:\

> Please fix it, I'm in hurry.

Seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Diamondback has been EOL (end of life) for a long time (http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29_Distribution_Releases). Please use currently supported distros such as hydro or indigo.

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2014-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rm4n2](https://answers.ros.org/users/19969/rm4n2/) on 2014-08-10**:
I'm trying to implement a code which is using ROS Diamondback, that's why i want to install Diamond back. What should i do?

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-08-10**:
I'm afraid you won't find much support for problems with Diamondback, in particular not for free, and certainly not by saying "I'm in a hurry". You can either try to fix issues yourself, or try to port the code to a recent ROS version.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-08-10**:
I suggest the latter. You can raise any concrete issues you encounter while porting the code here on answers.ros.org. If you ask politely, you might get some help.

**Comment by [Rm4n2aa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19982/rm4n2aa/) on 2014-08-10**:
Thanks for your help, I'll do the latter.
I really didn't mean to be rude, and I apologize for that.

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-08-10**:
No harm done. Just remember that most people here are donating their free time to help others. Keeping that in mind will increase your chances of getting help. Good luck with your code!